# Are $A,B$ similar matrices? Check my proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-verification

We are given $A,B$ are orthogonal $4$ by $4$ matrices with real values only.
We are given $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$ and $\mathrm{trace}(A) = \mathrm{trace}(B)$. Is $A$ similar to $B$?

My solution:

I think that it is, but a friend told me that she managed to contradict it.

I think they are similar because, the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. and since $A,B$ are orthogonal, we know all the eigenvalues are either $1$ or $-1$.

So the set of eigenvalues is any of the following:

$1,1,1,1$ or $1,1,-1,-1$ or $-1,-1,-1,-1$

Since $1+1+1+1 \neq 1+1-1-1 \neq -1-1-1-1$ we get that $A$ and $B$ must have the same set of eigenvalues. And so they are similar to the same diagonal matrix, and so they are similar to each other.

Where is the problem in this argument?

Comment: I think the argument's fine.

Comment: Yes, I edited that 1/2 second before your comment, @Git...thanks.

Comment: You mean all *eigenvalues* are real, or all *entries* are real?

Comment: @DonAntonio I take back my thanks and undelete my answer :P

Comment: Well, until the OP addresses the doubts in the comments I shall not add anything more to this...

Comment: What I meant is that the entries are real. I didn't say anything about the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this step:

> I think they are similar because, the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues. and since $A,B$ are orthogonal, we know all the eigenvalues are either $1$ or $−1$.

There are (real) orthogonal matrices which don't have real eigenvalues.

To look for simple counter examples, it might be useful to add the restriction $\text{trace}(A)=0=\text{trace}(B)$.

One of the simplest orthogonal matrices with non-real eigenvalues that comes to mind is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, so it's sensible to consider the block diagonal matrix $$\color{grey}{A:=}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 &-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

A matrix $B$ with real eigenvalues only which satisfies the conditions is easy is to find.

Comment: And have zero trace.

Comment: The OP though says the matrices *only* have real eigenvalues...